# String or Binary Data would be truncated asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

While inserting doc file in binary in data base. I am getting the error String or Binary Data would be truncated..

I have a web form like this

```
 <table>
<tr>
<td> 
    Select File
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ToolTip="Select Only Word File" />
    </td>
    <td> 
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="View Files" 
            onclick="Button2_Click" />
   </td>
    </tr>
```

code behind when user clicks on upload

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename1);
            string type = String.Empty;

            if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                Label2.Text = "Please Select File";
            }
            else
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        // Added by vithal wadje for Csharp-Corner contribution

                        switch (ext)
                        {
                            case ".doc":

                                type = "application/word";

                                break;

                            case ".docx":

                                type = "application/word";

                                break;

                        }

                        if (type != String.Empty)
                        {
                            connection();
                            Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                            query = "insert into test(data)" + " values (@Data)";
                            com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                            com.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;
                            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            Label2.Text = "Word File Uploaded successfully";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                            Label2.Text = "Select Only word Files";


                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();


                    }

                }
        }
```

In SQL Server I have database name test table name test

```
data varbinary(Max)
```

File which I am uploading has data `byte[9886].`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by we are trying to insert values in a column greater than the max size of the column specified so try to use Maximum Datatype

```
name Varchar(Max)
type Varchar(Max)
data VarBinary(Max)
```

Check your other columns that you are inserting into during this process.  I would especially check the `type` column as this will be something like `image/jpeg` and not simply image or jpeg.

Here is a [list of possible content types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) so that you can create enough space in your ContentType column accordingly.

Comment: no option is present in sql server for Binary(Max) while varbinary(Max) is there.. how cani fix this i am already assigning `binary(8000)` which is max value...

Comment: @Peter Henell used it but with no luck same exception is coming.

Comment: Have you tried setting the parameter datatype to SqlDbType.VarBinary

Comment: @Peter Henell Yes I set that too.

Comment: @Peter Henell can you please review my code I am stuck at this. Thank you.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Use Varbinary(max) then and also set maximum value for other two fileds

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar I have done that too. But I think problem is some thing else. Thank you for your replies :).

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Have you checked Content Type too?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad  i have  used your code. for me working clearly. May i know your word file size

Comment: I think  you need to split the file and store it in database

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar File size is 9.65kb

Comment: Will you store only this details or inserting anyother data while clicking button2 @AfnanAhmad

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar I am only storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size/ length of the SQL parameters to the actual bytes length.

```
com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
com.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, bytes.Length).Value = bytes;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or try setting the parameter length to -1 so that it would be translated by SQLClient as varbinary(MAX):

```
com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
com.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = bytes;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `VarBinary(MAX)` to resolve your problem, which increases the capacity to ~2GB, this likely isn't an ideal solution.

While you *can* store large quantities of binary data into a SQL database, you probably shouldn't.  Instead you should look at only storing a reference to that file, along with other metadata, and just storing that file onto disk.  You are likely better off just using a file server so that you avoid over-taxing your SQL server.

In the case that you want to stick to storing your files on a SQL server, take a look at using a VarBinary(MAX) FILESTREAM, which can then store even larger files and move the data faster.

More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx